# Run script on every level of directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix, directory-structure

I have a script called summarize.sh which produces a summary of the file/dirs inside of a directory. I would like to have it run recursively down the whole tree from the top. Whats a good way to do this?

I have tried to loop it with a for loop with

```
for dir in */; do
cd $dir
./summarize.sh
cd ..
```

however it returns ./summarize.sh: no file or directory
Is it because I am not moving the script as I run it? I am not very familiar with unix directories.

Comment: [How to go to each directory and execute a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7470165/608639), [Perform an action in every sub-directory using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4000613/608639), [How to enter all subdirectories and execute command on files inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42931420/608639), [Run a script from every directory on ubuntu linux](https://askubuntu.com/q/1115420), etc.

Comment: In each case where you want to do something on the contents of each directory beginning at some point in the filesystem, you will normally use `find /path/start -type d -exec someutility '{}' \;` where each directory is passed to the script `someutility` for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively list files using `find . -type f` and make your script take the interested file as a first argument, so you can do `find . -type f -exec myScript.sh {} \;`

If you want directories only, use `find . -type d` instead, or if you want both use just `find .` without restriction.

Additional option by name, e.g. `find . -name '*.py'`

Finally, if you do not want to recurse down the directory structure, i.e. only summarize the top level, you can use `-maxdepth 1` option, so something like `find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec myScript.sh {} \;`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are changing to a different directory with the `cd` command while your summarize.sh script is not located in these directories. One possible solution is to use an absolute path instead of a relative one. For example, change:

```
./summarize.sh
```

to something like:

```
/path/to/file/summarize.sh
```

Alternatively, under the given example code, you can also use a relative path pointing to the previous directory like this:

```
../summarize.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if you are running Bash 4.0 or later:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s nullglob   # Globs expand to nothing when they match nothing
shopt -s globstar   # Enable ** to expand over the directory hierarchy

summarizer_path=$PWD/summarize.sh

for dir in **/ ; do
    cd -- "$dir"
    "$summarizer_path"
    cd - >/dev/null
done
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` avoids an error in case there are no directories under the current one.
- The `summarizer_path` variable is set to an absolute path for the `summarize.sh` program.  That is necessary to allow it to be run in directories other than the current one.  (`./summarize.sh` only works in the current directory, `.`.)
- Use `cd -- ...` to avoid problems if any directory name begins with '-'.
- `cd - >/dev/null` to `cd` to the previous directory, and throw away its path when it is output by `cd -`.
- [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) issues several warnings about the code above, all to do with the use of `cd`.  I'd fix them for "real" code.

Comment: It returns an error ```/summarize.sh: No such                              file or directory``` for every directory it tried to run in

Comment: @llssff, check for typing errors on the `summarizer_path=$PWD/summarize.sh` line.  The [PWD](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PWD) built-in variable in Bash always contains the absolute path of the current directory.  It should never be undefined or empty.